# Automated Outllook Folder and Rules Generation

Tags: vba, powershell, outlook, ms-office, outlook-addin

I work in a customer-facing support job, and I see a lot of my colleagues using outlook to track support cases. They'll manually generate a new folder for each case number, and then manually generate a rule for each of those folders, moving emails from customers automatically to the folder with the same case number as in the subject field of the email.

I was wondering, perhaps using PowerShell, if there was a way to automate this process. A script you run, or even a third party tool? Or maybe even something we can run at the Exchange Server level?

Any insight to this situation would be greatly appreciated.

Happy Friday! Enjoy your weekends!

**Update**

I attempted to solve this solution with PowerShell myself, but most of the scripts I have tried to generate, or found online, requires you to create a text document with the folders you would like created. But this isn't a viable solution, as you don't always know which case number will be coming to your inbox.

So now I am trying it with a VBA Macro instead, couldn't sort this out with PowerShell, but the code fails.
Basically, it's supposed to do the following:

1. Scan all emails in a folder (Here it's Inbox->Customers->Name of Product I support) and find a 10 digit number in the subject line (this would be the ticket number or case ID number)
2. Then the macro is supposed to scan all folders, and see if a folder exists with the subject line, if it does, it moves the mail to it, if it doesn't, it creates the folder with the 10 digit number then moves the mail to it

I pasted the following in to "ThisOutlookSession" in Visual Basic, but the code fails (for various reasons as I keep playing with it)Currently getting "Object Doesn't Support This Property or Method":

```vba
Option Explicit
Private objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Private WithEvents objItems As Outlook.Items
Private WithEvents objSentItems As Outlook.Items
Dim strCode As String
Dim Code As String

Private m_Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Private m_Find As String

' False is slower but does not lock outlook up
' True is faster but outlook may not respond
Private Const SpeedUp As Boolean = False

Private Sub Application_Startup()

Dim objInboxFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim objSentFolder As Outlook.Folder
Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

'Set the folder and items to watch:
Set objInboxFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set objItems = objInboxFolder.Items

Set objSentFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
Set objSentItems = objSentFolder.Items

Set objSentFolder = Nothing
Set objInboxFolder = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub objItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
If Item.Class = olMail Then
    MoveMessages Item
End If
End Sub

Private Sub objSentItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
If Item.Class = olMail Then
    MoveMessages Item
End If
End Sub

Public Sub MoveMessages(ByVal Item As MailItem)
Dim strText As String
'' find the code
strText = Item.Subject & vbCrLf & Item.Body
strCode = ExtractText(strText)
If strCode = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

' if the code is in the message, find the folder
' move message
    FindFolder
    On Error Resume Next
    Item.Move m_Folder
      If m_Folder Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
      End If

Err.Clear
End Sub

Function ExtractText(Str As String) ' As String
Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim NumMatches As MatchCollection
Dim M As Match

'this pattern looks for 10 digits in the subject
With regEx
    .Pattern = "([0-9]{10})"
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Global = False
End With

Set NumMatches = regEx.Execute(Str)
If NumMatches.Count = 0 Then
      ExtractText = ""
Else
Set M = NumMatches(0)
  ExtractText = M.SubMatches(0)
End If
Code = ExtractText
End Function

' Borrowing Michael's code from
' http://vboffice.net/en/developers/find-folder-by-name

Public Sub FindFolder()
  Dim Name$
  Dim Folders As Outlook.Folders
  Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

  Set m_Folder = Nothing
  m_Find = ""

  Name = "*" & strCode
  If Len(Trim$(Name)) = 0 Then Exit Sub
  m_Find = Name

  m_Find = LCase$(m_Find)

  Set Folder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Customers("NameOfProduct")
  LoopFolders Folder.Folders

End Sub

Private Sub LoopFolders(Folders As Outlook.Folders)
  Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim F As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim Found As Boolean
  
  If SpeedUp = False Then DoEvents

  For Each F In Folders
      Found = (LCase$(F.Name) Like m_Find)

    If Found Then
      Set m_Folder = F
      Exit For
    Else
      LoopFolders F.Folders
      If Not m_Folder Is Nothing Then Exit For
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not solving this exact problem, but I am hacking through using powershell to back-up individual emails/meetings/etc to a folder so I don't have to rely on a .pst file.

Here are some code blocks that can help you create folders.

### Get setup

```
# Start fresh outlook
if (Get-Process -Name Outlook -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
    Write-Host "Outlook is running - terminating process"
    Stop-Process -Name Outlook
}
# Set the path to save the backup files
$backup_path = "C:\test\test"   

# Powershell couldn't open outlook dll from my user directory
# So we change to assembly files and then back to working dir
$original_pwd = (Get-Location).Path 
cd "$env:windir\assembly"
$interop_assem_location = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll).Directory
cd $interop_assem_location 
Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" 
cd "$original_pwd"
```

### Accessing Outlook via powershell

##### You should be able to find enough to modify the loop to check for duplicate files and other error prone stuff.

- In the below snippet, you will need to modify any of the conditions being pulled from the outlook items.
- For example if your case numbers or emails follow a regex pattern, you can insert that as a variable.
- Then the part you need to build is creating rules or anything other than adding a folder name, which is there.

```
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$folder = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder(6)  # Inbox = 6
foreach ($item in $folder.Items) {
    # Skip non-email items like calendar events
    if ($item.MessageClass -ne "IPM.Note") {
        continue
    {
    
    # Get the unique subject (and date for the filename)
    # $date = $item.ReceivedTime.ToString("yyMMMdd")
    ## INSERT REGEX OR SOMETHING HERE - this one looks for word case surrounded by any number of spaces, then some case number with a dash
    # example: foo bar **CASE** foos bas **33341-123** las
    # $regex = "(\s+(CASE+\s+)+)([A-Za-z0-9]+(-[A-Za-z0-9]+)+)"
    # $subregx = [regex]::matches($item.$subject, $regex).value
    $foldname = "$subregx-$date"
    $folder.Folders.Add($foldname)
}
```

Comment: First, sorry for the delay. Thanks for the input, I will try to play around with this and see if I can get a script working to generate what I need it to do. Not really a PowerShell guy to be honest, but I'll see what I can come up with. 

I'll post results, if I have any, in the thread.

Comment: Can you post some generic email headers that you would expect to search for in the script?
I recently solved my problem and was curious if i could adapt it here, but I just don't know the scope.

Comment: Couldn't edit in time.. :(
Can you post some generic email headers that you would expect to search for in the script?

In your update post, i think i have a solution for #2, but not enough info on #1.
Does the script need to scan the entire inbox and copy then delete items? I would probably just copy, then ask users to manually delete to avoid scrutiny or errors.
Or run nightly a qc version that deletes duplicates